# Can I prevent a local user from snooping on HTTPS headers containing a manager password?

Tags: security, hash, https, passwords, bcrypt

My program sends a request to a web page over SSL and in the header (https://example.com/index.php?clientid=xxxx?spcode=xxxx) is a manager password used to determine if they are a valid client of my system before I send them a bunch of data.

If a rogue employee were to obtain this password by snooping on the local SSL data, he could potentially toy with client orders being sent and received if he were to guess order numbers (not hard).

I'm aware of how to use bcrypt to protect someone's password on my system. But how do I protect someone's password when *someone else* is using they're system?

I know you shouldn't send a pre-hashed password at risk of revealing your salt. Should I use some soft of temporary transmission hash (one that differs from what I store it in the DB with). I'm thinking this isn't the best way, so I'm asking you all for help. I've found some great tips here at Stack Exchange.

Thank you in advance for your time, everyone. I look forward to your thoughts.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how HTTPS and SSL work. Also if you're passing username/password as GET parameters (in the URL) you should rethink that and use POST parameters or in AUTH headers, URLs can be retrieved from browser histories. To successfully man in the middle you, the malicious employee would need to control your router

Comment: Understood, it was written to work first and go back later to make secure. Like anything rushed. That leads me to a question, If I use MSXML2.XmlHttp or System.XML through a VB.Net app, is that data put into Internet Explorer's browser history even though I'm not using it through the browser?

Comment: Nope. But it's likely to go into the server's request log.

Comment: Actually, they can use the IE cache in some cases, but even when you go for the most cache-loving options in .NET, it wouldn't for an HTTPS request that wasn't marked as cacheable in the server's headers.

Answer (score 5):

Snooping on SSL can only be done by man-in-the-middling, and that's detected.

Consider how if you do so in fiddler, the browser reacts by complaining about the certificate. Of course, since you trust you not to spy on you, you okay it!

Comparably, you're going to see that you aren't dealing with a server with the correct certificate. If your app refuses to deal with other certificates, then it won't allow the SSL connection to be estabilshed, and there's no snooping.

I'd still recommend sending the password in authentication headers though, as per RFC 2617, NTLM, or so on. Especially if you move to also doing server-to-browser on top of the same system later, and wouldn't want them to be snoopable from the address bar.

Edit: Depending on what you write the app in, it can be temporarily allowing snooping for debugging purposes that proves trickier!

Comment: Great info, thank you. I will read the appropriate RFC 2617 sections. My app is VB.Net - what would happen if someone 'fiddled' with it? I am using MSXML2.XmlHttp to retrieve the page. The other end is a PHP app running on a dedicated host with an SSL certificate.

Comment: What are you writing it in, chances are you already have access to what it describes (not that I'd ever discourage someone from reading an RFC, and for that matter 2616 is a must when you do anything with HTTP from an app, just that you hopefully won't have to implement the support yourself).

Comment: Ah. You could try yourself and see. Launch Fiddler http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ set it to interpret HTTPS (test it works correctly in browser), and then use it as a proxy for your app. Hopefully your app will error because the SSL is being man-in-the-middled. Why use MSXML2.XmlHttp from .NET rather than the System.Xml classes?

Comment: I think originally because we were tinkering with some AJAX long polling stuff which was scrapped and that was the known method to do it. I will definitely do some fiddling tonight.

Comment: `XmlDocument` for parsing and `HttpWebRequest` or the new `WebClient` shouldn't hold many surprises for someone who's used MSXML2, but be more flexible and cleaner. The other approaches .NET offers are worth learning too, but if you're used to MSXML2 they should be a doddle to get used to.

Comment: +1 - Of course, this assumes that the request is not set over HTTP in the first place, and then "upgraded" to HTTPS by the web server. It has to be HTTPS the whole way though. Oh, and don't use NTLM; it was hopelessly broken a long time ago.